# How do you 'continue' like with for loops when iterating with a closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using underscore.js is there a way to breakout of the each if a certain condition is met?

```
_.each([1,2,3], function(value) {
  if (value == 2) {
    // continue 2
    return false;
  }
});
```

I'm sure returning false did the trick in prototype.js

Comment: You could always throw an exception, but that seems pretty clumsy.

Comment: [This issue addresses the problem that you cannot do this](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/211). Underscore has a `breaker` property you can return internally to break `_.each`. it's not public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you should return `breaker`, which isn't in scope it seems. So, without modifying `_`, you can't easily break out of iteration. The `===` there will ensure that returning `{}` won't cause the loop to break; you need a reference to `breaker`, which you don't have.

```
 // The cornerstone, an `each` implementation, aka `forEach`.
  // Handles objects implementing `forEach`, arrays, and raw objects.
  // Delegates to **ECMAScript 5**'s native `forEach` if available.
  var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
      obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (_.isNumber(obj.length)) {
      for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (i in obj && iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
      }
    } else {
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
          if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: You might want to report this as a bug or feature request. Also note that if your object supports `forEach`, then you can't break also.

Comment: Here is how prototype.js handles it: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each

Comment: So is it possible to break out of the native forEach?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can actually stop the loop but you could use a boolean to stop the code in the loop from executing:

```
var keep_going = true;
_.each([1,2,3], function(value) {
  if(keep_going){
    if (value == 2) {
      // continue 2
      keep_going = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. As Stefan posted above, if your browser does not support Array.prototype.forEach (which is a long shot these days), you could return `breaker` -- if you had access to it. But unfortunately, you don't, because `breaker` is defined as `{}` in a closure in the underscore.js library.

Unfortunately, the behavior of JavaScript is that two objects are not equal to one another unless they are the exact same object. Therefore, `({}) === ({})` is false -- and so returning `{}` from your function will not pass an equality check with the internal `breaker` variable.

So, you can't break out of loops like this without roundabout methods like posted above. And, according to [the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach), there is no way to break the native forEach that is used.

Answer (score 1):

It may very well be that `.each` does not support skipping.

You can do it the roundabout way:

```
var skip = false;
_.each([1,2,3], function(value) {
  if (true === skip) {
    return;
  }
  if (value == 2) {
    skip = true;
    return false;
  }
});
```

But I'm sure there is a better function for it.

Comment: In JavaScript, Yoda conditions not necessary are. ;)

Comment: Yoda conditions I write because my sanity I want to keep. Also triple equals I use because coercion I do not like. And why are Yoda conditions not necessary in JavaScript? You can still incorrectly write `if (skip = true)`

Comment: Okay, maybe it's a matter of taste. I just don't like them, but I do see your point.

Comment: Why not be consistent then and write `if (2 == value)`? :p